# GraphView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tree

I'm trying to create a tree structure where, when I click on add button available on the node, then its two child node should be created. My simple code is given below where, when I'm trying to add the child node, it is randomly generated as a child of any given random node. Please suggest what should I do in the code to get my requirement, and also I want to give them ascending order.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphview/GraphView.dart';
class MyGraphView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyGraphView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyGraphViewState createState() => _MyGraphViewState();
}

 class _MyGraphViewState extends State<MyGraphView> {
 Random r = Random();
 final Graph graph = Graph()..isTree = true;
 BuchheimWalkerConfiguration builder = BuchheimWalkerConfiguration();
 @override
 void initState() {
final node1 = Node.Id(1);
final node2 = Node.Id(2);
final node3 = Node.Id(3);
graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
graph.addEdge(node1, node3, paint: Paint());
builder
  ..siblingSeparation = (50)
  ..levelSeparation = (50)
  ..subtreeSeparation = (50)
  ..orientation = (BuchheimWalkerConfiguration.ORIENTATION_TOP_BOTTOM);
 }
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Center(
    child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("GraphView Example"),),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [

            Expanded(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                  constrained: false,
                  boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  minScale: 0.01,
                  maxScale: 5.6,
                  child: GraphView(
                    graph: graph,
                    algorithm: BuchheimWalkerAlgorithm(
                        builder, TreeEdgeRenderer(builder)),
                    paint: Paint()
                      ..color = Colors.green
                      ..strokeWidth = 1
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
                    builder: (Node node) {
                      var a = node.key?.value as int;
                      return rectangleWidget(a);
                    },
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
   );
  }
  Widget rectangleWidget(int a) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Node $a Clicked"),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2, milliseconds: 500),
    )
    );
    // print('clicked');
  },
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      boxShadow: const [
        BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, spreadRadius: 1),
      ],
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.green, spreadRadius: 1),
              ],
            ),
            child: Text('Node $a')
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 10,),

        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            add();
          },
          child: Container(
            //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, spreadRadius: 1),
              ],
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
  );
 }
add(){
  final node3 = Node.Id(r.nextInt(100));
  var edge = graph.getNodeAtPosition(
     r.nextInt(graph.nodeCount()));
  print(edge);
  graph.addEdge(edge, node3);
  setState(() {});
}
}
```